# returning Javascript onclick prevents button from using it's action

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton, onclick

The action part of my button stops working as soon as I change my button to return my javascript confirmation.

Javascript:

```
function confirmDialog()
{
    var confirmation = confirm('Once you submit this record for approval, you might not be able to edit it or recall it from the approval process depending on your settings. Continue?');
    return confirmation;
}
```

Not working VF:

```
<apex:commandButton title="Submit this rebate for approval" value="Submit Rebate for Approval" action="{!submitForApproval}" rendered="{!!renderCloseButton}" rerender="forecastSection, rebateMessages, fullBlock" onclick="return confirmDialog();" />
```

Working VF:

```
<apex:commandButton title="Submit this rebate for approval" value="Submit Rebate for Approval" action="{!submitForApproval}" rendered="{!!renderCloseButton}" rerender="forecastSection, rebateMessages, fullBlock" onclick="confirmDialog();" />
```

The only difference in the working/non-working is returning the onclick.  I want my action to only fire if my confirmation returns true.  The second set calls the action method but regardless of their response on the confirmation dialog.  I have another button with the exact same setup, but it works as I expect.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I could not have a rerender when returning the 'onclick'.  I had to work around this.  The new pieces:

New Action Function:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="approvalJS" action="{!submitForApproval}" rerender="forecastSection, rebateMessages, fullBlock" />
```

New outputPanel for rerendering (This is required to prevent the entire page from refreshing on my button press):

```
<apex:outputPanel id="pointlessRerender" />
```

Updated confirmDialog:

```
function confirmDialog()
{
    var confirmation = confirm('Once you submit this record for approval, you might not be able to edit it or recall it from the approval process depending on your settings. Continue?');

    if (confirmation)
    {
        approvalJS();
    }
}
```

Updated button:

```
<apex:commandButton title="Submit this rebate for approval" value="Submit Rebate for Approval"  rendered="{!!renderCloseButton}" onclick="confirmDialog();" reRender="pointlessRerender" />
```